# Mac Sandbox issues with opening embedded RTF files

Tags: swift, macos, sandbox, nsworkspace

My Mac programs usually ship with some internal Rich Text files containing legal details.  I use the NSWorkspace openFile call to open the files within TextEdit.

The code looks something like this:

```
guard let aPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: “Legal.rtf”, ofType: nil) else { return }
NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(aPath, withApplication: nil)
```

This has always worked, until recently when this code returns “The application can’t be opened. -50”.  Is that a Sandbox issue?  Accessing files within your bundle should be allowed. We do it for images and such.

What do I have set wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: The very first line is wrong.

Comment: Is the value of `aPath` correct? Have you tried resource "Legal" of type "rtf"?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments.

I should have mentioned at first that parameter string I had included both filename and the file type (extension).  So I would have to split them, something that was easy to do with NSString, but is not immediately available for Swift String. A bit of conversion would have given me the two strings.

However, that OpenFile has been replaced with the newer open(_:)

```
let name = "Legal.rtf"

guard let aURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "") else { return }

NSWorkspace.shared.open(aURL)
```

This call does NOT mind if you pass it string with both parts.

Comment: *...but is not immediately available for Swift String*. Really? What `NSString` API are you talking about? And your example shows a string literal which is not that hard to split anyway.